# How to select which SQL backup set to restore from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to restore a sql database programatically from C#. My .bak file contains several backup sets. I want to restore them all at the same time.

When I run the following sql script I succeed to restore the oldest backup set:

```
ALTER DATABASE [My_DB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
RESTORE DATABASE [My_DB] FROM DISK = 'C:\backup.bak' WITH REPLACE;
```

Is it possible to select which backup set to restore?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [RESTORE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx). Not sure what this has to do with c# though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't think that's related to `C#`, it's related to `T-SQL`.*

T-SQL `restore` will allow you to define which file restore from the backup-set. It can easily be defined by using `WITH FILE=number_of_file`.

Here is an example from MSDN article [**Complete Database Restores (Full Recovery Model)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187495.aspx):

```
USE master;  
--Create tail-log backup.  
BACKUP LOG AdventureWorks2012   
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorksFullRM.bak'    
   WITH NORECOVERY;   
GO  
--Restore the full database backup (from backup set 1).  
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012   
  FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorksFullRM.bak'   
  WITH FILE=1,   
    NORECOVERY;  

--Restore the regular log backup (from backup set 2).  
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2012   
  FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorksFullRM.bak'   
  WITH FILE=2,   
    NORECOVERY;  

--Restore the tail-log backup (from backup set 3).  
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2012   
  FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorksFullRM.bak'  
  WITH FILE=3,   
    NORECOVERY;  
GO  
--recover the database:  
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 WITH RECOVERY;  
GO
```

I suggest you to take a look at this workaround too:

[**Restore a DB to the latest file in a backup set:**](https://serverfault.com/a/573547)

```
declare @dbname varchar(80),
        @lastfull datetime,
        @fullback varchar(1024),
        @position int,
        @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @dbname = 'YourDB'


select @lastfull = MAX(backup_finish_date) 
FROM master.sys.databases d
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b ON d.name = b.database_name AND b.type = 'D'
WHERE d.database_id NOT IN (2, 3) and d.name=@dbname


SELECT    @fullback = m.physical_device_name, @position = b.position
FROM         msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS m INNER JOIN
                      msdb.dbo.backupset AS b ON m.media_set_id = b.media_set_id 
                      and b.type='D' and b.database_name=@dbname
                      AND b.backup_finish_date=@lastfull


set @SQL =  'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @DBname + '] FROM  DISK = N''' + @fullback +  ''' WITH  FILE = ' + convert(nvarchar,@position) + ',  RECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```